# PHP string comparison. Regex

Tags: php, regex, fopen, string-comparison

We are trying to display whether a file contains a specific string or not:

Here we read the file:

```
$myFile = "filename.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile,'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize("filename.txt"));
fclose($fh);
```

filename.txt contains "Offline"

Here we are trying to compare the strings:

```
if(strcmp($theData,"Online")==0){
echo "Online"; }
elseif(strcmp($theData,"Offline")==0) {
echo "Offline"; }
else {
echo "This IF is not working." }
```

We have tried using regular if without the strcomp, but it did not work either. I'm thinking that an IF cannot compare the results from the fread to a regular string. Perhaps we will need to try another method.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to do a var_dump() of $theData to know the type and get more information.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($theData)`?

Answer (score 5):

Use `preg_match()`

```
$string = "your-string";
$pattern = "/\boffline\b/i"; 

// The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct 
// word "offline" is matched; if you want to match even partial word "offline"
// within some word, change the pattern to this /offline/i

if(preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
}
```

You can use `strpos()` as well (it is faster in this case)

```
$string = 'your-stringoffline';
$find   = 'offline';
$pos = strpos($string, $find);

if($pos !== false){
    echo "The string '$find' was found in the string '$string' at position $pos";
}else{
    echo "The string '$find' was not found in the string '$string'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is very slow when used to search in long strings. use strpos

```
$strFile = file_get_contents("filename.txt"); // load file
if(strpos($strFile, 'Online')!==false){ // check if "Online" exists
    echo "We are Online";
    }
elseif(strpos($strFile, 'Offline')!==false){ // check if "Offline" exists
    echo "We are Offline";
    }
else{ // other cases
    echo "Status is unknown";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put another way to do that (depending what it is inside the file), although it is not the best it may be useful in some circumstances

```
if (exec("grep Offline filename.txt") === 'Offline')
    echo 'Offline';
else
    echo 'Online';
```

Byee

Answer (score -1):

Are you checked the value contains in $theData ?

Try something like this:

```
if(strcmp($theData,"Online") === 0)
   echo $theData." is equal to string Online using case sensisive"; 
else if(strcmp($theData,"Offline") === 0)
   echo $theData." is equal to string Offline using case sensisive"; 
else
   echo $theData." This IF is not working.";
```

Here the doc for more infos: http://php.net//manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Or using the **hex494D49's** method: **(Not tested)**

```
function isStringAreTheSame($initialString, $stringToCompare) {
   $pattern = "/\b".$initialString."\b/";

   return preg_match($pattern, $stringToCompare);
}
```

Comment: `$pattern = "/\b".$initialString."\b/"` or you'll get `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in...`

Comment: I have updated my post with your suggestion ;) Thank you for this ;)